# How to disable multitouch when having several views?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, multi-touch

I created my own custom view that extends UIControl. This custom view has its own touch implementation. I implemented touchesBegan, Moved, Ended, and Canceled methods in it.

In the main view controller, I created several instances of this view. So in the screen, there are a number of custom buttons.

I want to disable multitouch in my app. If I click one custom button, then other buttons shouldn't respond.

Actually, it was easy to implement this. While I held some buttons, I could just make other buttons' userInteractionEnabled property to NO until I ended touch.

**But the problem is that when I tap these several buttons at the same time, two or more touchesBegan methods work simultaneously, and message passing is messed up.**

I tried to set multiTouchEnabled = NO and exclusiveTouch = YES, but it still didn't work.

**How can I force to disable multitouch in my app?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `exclusiveTouch` to `YES`, not `NO` (which is the default anyways). The name of the property refers to the view being the exclusive recipient of any touch events for the duration.

Comment: oh.. sorry. I mistyped them. I set exclusiveTouch to YES, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @kyu You might need to call `super` in your implementations of `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and friends, as the superclass might contain the logic for handling `exclusiveTouch` properly.